# Angularjs ng-repeat, ng-form and validation error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A simplified version of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("main", []);
        app.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
            $scope.addresses = [{street: ""}, {street: ""}];
            $scope.next = function() {
                if ($scope.addressMainForm.addressForm.$valid) {
                    console.log("valid");
                } else {
                    console.log("invalid");
                }
                $scope.addresses.push({street: ""});
            };
            $scope.remove = function(index) {
                $scope.addresses.splice(index, 1);
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="TestController" style="width: 500px;">
        <form name="addressMainForm">
            <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
                <ng-form name="addressForm">
                    <input ng-model="address.street" required name="street" type="text" placeholder="street" />
                    <button ng-if="$index > 0" ng-click="remove($index)">REMOVE</button>
                </ng-form>
                <br>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br>
        <button ng-click="next()">NEXT</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

which looks in the browser like this:

[image]

When I click "REMOVE" and then "NEXT" - javascript error is produced:

```
Error: $scope.addressMainForm.addressForm is undefined
```

Why is it undefined if there is clearly still one element remaining in the array? Everything otherwise works fine (`console.log` output), until all the elements are removed but the last one and "NEXT" is clicked.

Comment: Did you try to print the `$scope.addressMainForm` in the console log to see its content?

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. Yes, and the property `addressForm` is gone, for some reason removing next to last element from array `$scope.addresses` also removes that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$scope.addressMainForm.addressForm.$valid` , you are attempting to call check to see if the `adressForm` element is valid, but your `remove` function has removed the `addresses` entry associated with that element. So the form indeed still exists, but that call becomes illegal.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("main", []);
        app.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
            $scope.addresses = [{street: ""}, {street: ""}];
            $scope.next = function() {
                if ($scope.addressMainForm.$valid) {
                    console.log("valid");
                } else {
                    console.log("invalid");
                }
                $scope.addresses.push({street: ""});
            };
            $scope.remove = function(index) {
                $scope.addresses.splice(index, 1);
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="TestController" style="width: 500px;">
        <form name="addressMainForm">
            <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
                <ng-form name="addressForm">
                    <input ng-model="address.street" required name="street" type="text" placeholder="street" />
                    <button ng-if="$index > 0" ng-click="remove($index)">REMOVE</button>
                </ng-form>
                <br>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br>
        <button ng-click="next()">NEXT</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```